# Cyrillic symbols are not displayed

Tags: beamer, xetex, pdftex, babel, cyrillic

I'm trying to compile a template babel based presentation on my machine. And I can not get cyrillic symbols displayed.

The problem is that it won't produce any useful output. Build process seems to end without any errors, but text is not displayed.

I also tried to build it with pdflatex and I succeeded. Usually I use XeTeX.

Any ideas on how can I fix it? It's not that I need to use XeTeX too much, but I've wasted few hours on that and I'm curious.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

% Стиль презентации

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\title{Все что вы хотели знать о сферическом коне в вакууме, но боялись спросить}  
\author{Олень Северный}
\institute{Научно исследовательский институт физико-матетматических проблем}
\date{Москва, 2010} 
% Создание заглавной страницы
\frame{\titlepage} 
% Автоматическая генерация содержания
\frame{\frametitle{Содержание}\tableofcontents} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` -- that should bring the right encoding given that your file is saved in `utf8` encoding...

Comment: XeTeX ignores it. It actually displays a warning, when this command is issued.

Comment: You asked for `pdflatex`

Comment: Sorry, but I've mentioned that pdflatex built it. And my actual question was whether I can build it with XeTeX or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using the `lmodern` package, which sets the document fonts to *Latin Modern*, but it doesn't have support for cyrillic letters. There's *Computer Modern Uncode* for cyrillic and greek.

For XeLaTeX, add

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  BoldFont=cmunbx,
  ItalicFont=cmunti,
  BoldItalicFont=cmunbi,
]{cmunrm}
\setsansfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  BoldFont=cmunsx,
  ItalicFont=cmunsi,
]{cmunss}
```

just before `\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}`, assuming that `cm-unicode` is installed into your TeX distribution.

For LuaLaTeX it's sufficient to add

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}[Ligatures=TeX]
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}[Ligatures=TeX]
```

and if you want to use good old pdfLaTeX, just add the usual

```
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

(in all cases remove the `\usepackage{lmodern}` line).

Note, that for pdfLaTeX the correct fonts are selected automagically after you specify the font encoding (T2A), but for LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX you'd have to set them explicitly which is a pity.

Answer (score 4):

I've compiled with [OVERLEAF](https://www.overleaf.com). I hope I have helped you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Стиль презентации

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\title{Все что вы хотели знать о сферическом коне в вакууме, но боялись спросить}  
\author{Олень Северный}
\institute{Научно исследовательский институт физико-матетматических проблем}
\date{Москва, 2010} 
% Создание заглавной страницы
\frame{\titlepage} 
% Автоматическая генерация содержания
\frame{\frametitle{Содержание}\tableofcontents} 
\end{document}
```